# Abrir archivos en el directorio público con app de terceros usando File Provider

Tags: android

Recientemente estoy trabajando en el desarrollo de una app para la descarga masiva de archivos de peso considerable. Éstos se guardan en el directorio público de Descargas (`Environment.DIRECTORY_DOWNLOADS`). Además éstos son listados en mi aplicación para ser abiertos con una app de terceros y con la salida de Android 7 necesito adaptarla con el uso del File Provider. El problema es que al intentar realizar el Intent se me muestra la siguiente excepción.

```
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Failed to find configured root that contains
/storage/emulated/0/Download/CBgraphic/example.jpg
```

La manera en la que lo estoy intentando es la siguiente:

**Provider**

```
<provider
        android:authorities="${applicationId}.provider"
        android:name="android.support.v4.content.FileProvider"
        android:exported="false"
        android:grantUriPermissions="true">
        <meta-data
            android:name="android.support.FILE_PROVIDER_PATHS"
            android:resource="@xml/provider_path"/>
    </provider>
```

**xml: provider_path**

```
<paths xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
<external-path name="Download" path="."/></paths>
```

**Código del intent**

```
String CBDirectory = Environment.getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(
    Environment.DIRECTORY_DOWNLOADS).getPath() + File.separator + "CBgraphic" +
    File.separator;
File current_file = new File(CBDirectory + "example.jpg");

MimeTypeMap myMime = MimeTypeMap.getSingleton();
Intent newIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
String ext = extFile(current_file.getName());
String mimeType = myMime.getMimeTypeFromExtension(ext);
newIntent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
newIntent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_GRANT_READ_URI_PERMISSION);
newIntent.setDataAndType(FileProvider.getUriForFile(ctx, ctx.getPackageName()+".provider",
    current_file),mimeType);
startActivity(newIntent);
```

Espero que puedan apoyarme en intentar entender qué está pasando. De antemano gracias.